# What is default behavior for actioncable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

When generating a new channel, there is commented out stream_from method call. I understand, that it suits for recognizing streams, like stream_from "comments_#{message.id}".

But if this channel has no such goal and should stream all comments? What is default behavior (of value maybe) of this channel without specifying stream_from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming that your channel is named `SomethingChannel`

```
class SomethingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # because you do not need stream_from, then remove the stream_from below
    # stream_from "something_channel"

    # and just immediately transmit the data. This should be a hash, and thus I use `as_json`; Change this accordingly as you see fit
    transmit(Comment.all.as_json)
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Then on the client-side, you just simply invoke the following whenever you already need this.

```
# ...coffee
App.cable.subscriptions.create 'SomethingChannel',
  connected: ->
    console.log('connected')

  # Called when the WebSocket connection is closed.
  disconnected: ->
    console.log('disconnected')

  # `transmit(Comment.all.as_json)` above will invoke this
  received: (data) ->
    console.log('received')
    console.log(data)
```

You should see the something like the following in your Google Chrome / Firefox console:

```
connected
received
▼ [{…}]
  ▶ 0: {id: 1, title: "Hello ", content: "World from Earth! :)", created_at: "2018-02-13T16:15:05.734Z", updated_at: "2018-02-13T16:15:05.734Z"}
  ▶ 1: {id: 2, title: "Lorem ", content: "Ipsum Dolor", created_at: "2018-02-13T16:15:05.734Z", updated_at: "2018-02-13T16:15:05.734Z"}
  length: 2
  ▶ __proto__: Array(0)
```

*P.S. if you are not gonna make use of `stream_from` or `stream_for` then perhaps you might not need `ActionCable` after all, and perhaps you'd be better off retrieving all the comments from an API instead (i.e. `GET /comments`)*

Comment: I dont understand. I just use ActionCable.server.broadcast to broadcast some data to subscribers. But what first argument should I pass to ActionCable.server.broadcast if I didnt set stream_from? In tutorials, ActionCable.server.broadcast first argument and stream_from argument are equal. But what is the default one?

Comment: If you're going to do `ActionCable.server.broadcast`, you need to use `stream_for` or `stream_from`. The main reason is for scalability. You'll need to have a central place for all subscribers to listen to, which is the "broadcasting name" (the same value you pass to `stream_for(broadcasting_name)`). This "broadcasting name" resides in a central distribution place, which is normally your `redis` configure for `ActionCable`.

Comment: ... the problem with not using a "broadcasting name" is that your application may have lots of computers/servers each running their own Rails server of your app (to be able to handle loooooads of concurrent requests), and that you didn't use a central place "broadcasting name" / redis), then `ActionCable.server.broadcast` can only broadcast to all the Websocket connections that are currently connected to it but only in one server,and not all of your servers because each server has its own "memory" space,and they cannot automatically access each other's "memory" in which the connections resides

Comment: If you insist however on not wanting to use `stream_from` but at the same time you wanted to be able to "broadcast" (like `ActionCable.server.broadcast`), then you can do something like: `ObjectSpace.each_object(SomethingChannel) { |something_channel_instance| something_channel_instance.connection.transmit(YOURDATA) }`
However that will only work in the same server (multi-processes nor multi-servers wont work), and it's really not a recommended way on doing it, and you'll probably be having maintenance problems in the long-run. Also, I haven't fully tested if this even works.